# he would have helped me if necessary

Tags: modal-verbs

1. (I think) *he would have helped me* if necessary.

Does the italicized part refer to getting help *only in the past*, or does it refer to getting help *at any time (including the future)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to what is implied in the sentence below but is not actually written.

> *he would have helped me* if necessary.

By the tense used throughout the sentence we can know that it relates to an event in the past. However if the statement had been

> *he would help me* if I asked.

Then this could be a different matter. We often use would to make hypotheses.

hypothesis; noun; an idea or explanation for something that is based on known facts but has not yet been proven: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypothesis)